# How can I connect Flutter in VS Code with the BlueStacks 4 emulator?

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, flutter, flutter-layout, bluestacks

How can I connect Flutter with VS Code to emulator BlueStacks 4.  I do not want to use Android Studio because it is bad software. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 7):

**For this we need to establish ADB(Android Debug Bridge) connection between VScode and Android Emulator(Bluestacks) which has PID(Process identifier) 5555**

For time save first check, status bar of VScode to check device connection. Two case possible show below :
[image]

[image]

If you are fall under 2nd case so it is good to go with debugging. And no need look at other points.

In all other case let's establish connection. Steps are

1. Open Bluestacks and go to settings by clicking on   **≡**  like icon.
   [image]
2. Then move to preferences and then scroll down and turn on Abd connection
3. In terminal type `adb connect localhost:5555`
   [image]
4. Now check again status bar in VScode. Status of devices will be present

Comment: That works but every single time I start Bluestacks again I have to connect again. Is there any way to make it work forever?

Comment: As we all know that when ever we restart our system this port `192.168.0.1:5555`  get close automatically. One thing you can do just open this `port` in firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it.
Just open bluestacks and go to settings.
Then go to preferences and tick the checkbox just beside the option enable Android Debug Bridge(ADB).
Then if you open Visual Studio Code and search for devices you will find bluestacks android emulator in the list of devices.

Hope it helps...[image]

Answer (score 1):

**step 1:**
go to setting button on bluestack
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p7JG.png)

**step 2:**
then go to the advance and ensure that ADB is turn on
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mjDF.png)

**step 3:**
after that, you must to restart your bluestacks, then open a terminal and go to your Android SDK folder: ../Android/Sdk/platform-tools/ and copy this path
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1PGR.png)

**step 4:**
Now change the directory by cd with this path and run this command:
**adb connect localhost:5555**
if this command is not working then use this command :
**.\adb connect localhost:5555**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHt5k.png)

**step 5:**
Now choose the device and run your project. It may take some times so keep patient for that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ8ss.png)

Answer (score 0):

The VS Code extension uses the `flutter devices` command to find devices. This is turn uses `adb devices`. In order for emulators to be usable in VS Code you should make sure that a) it shows up in `adb devices` and b) Flutter is able to find your Android SDK (the best way to check if this is the case is running the `Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor` command from the VS Code command palette, which will run `doctor` with the same environment that VS Code has).

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `adb` on BlueStacks Configs.
It is on Right upper side Gear, `Config / Advanced / enable adb`

Hope You can use it.

Comment: after that, you must to restart your bluestacks, then open a terminal and go to your Android SDK folder:

    ../Android/Sdk/platform-tools/

then type the follow commands:

    adb connect localhost:5555

So, by now if you type `flutter devices` you will get the emulator device name on the list, then you can run your apps on it