# Bluestack Restart, Flutter could detect it

Tags: flutter, bluestacks

#### Problem Description

When I first open bluestack, my flutter could detect it.
https://prnt.sc/rmyr5v

However, when I restart my bluestack, flutter could not detect it. Anyone know why would this happened and how to solve it?
https://prnt.sc/rmylt4

Answer (score 0):

It is because of port may automatically turn off.
First check this dicussion [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65399793/15295234) and turn on all setting provide here

```
Follow the steps:   

1. Open terminal
2. Type flutter connect localhost:<post-name>
And this port establish connection between vscode and bluestacks
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my discussion solution.